# Why is this happening? Oops

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
Sorry, we can't accept this question.
```

From yesterday I am not able to ask some questions, Why is it happening?

Answer (score 3):

There are certain quality filters we apply to incoming questions.

Make sure your question has

- a clear title
- a reasonable *explanation* of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
- correct use of English and actual sentences

Also, if your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit here.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday the site was having some issues. Network, or otherwise.

It seems to be fixed now.